# Using defaultdict to append to list of strings

Tags: python

**Background**

I am new to python and using types. I am basically trying to use defaultdict to populate a dictionary that contains a string as key and values which are List of strings.

**Code**

```
from typing import DefaultDict, List
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict: DefaultDict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(List[str])

my_dict["Lebron"] = "goat"
my_dict["Lebron"] = "king"

print(my_dict)
```

My current output is `defaultdict(typing.List[str], {'Lebron': 'king'})` i expect it to be `defaultdict(typing.List[str], {'Lebron': ['goat','king']})` instead.

**Issue**
if i change my code to use append like this i get an error

```
from typing import DefaultDict, List
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict: DefaultDict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(List[str])

my_dict["Lebron"].append("goat")
my_dict["Lebron"].append("king")

print(my_dict)
```

**Error**

```
    raise TypeError(f"Type {self._name} cannot be instantiated; "
TypeError: Type List cannot be instantiated; use list() instead
```

Comment: Use `defaultdict(list)` instead of `defaultdict(List[str])` (And go the append route).

Comment: Yes, `defaultdict(List[str])` requires a real type, `List[str]` is not a real type, it meant solely for use as a type annotation. You must use `lst`. so `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: that works! thanks, if you post answer i can upvote and accept .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga has already mentioned, `List[str]` is just type annotation.

Use

```
my_dict: DefaultDict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(list)
```

And go the append route.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
from typing import DefaultDict, List
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict: DefaultDict[str, List[str]] = defaultdict(List[str])

my_dict["Lebron"] = ["goat", "king"]

print(my_dict)
```